# jconsole to connect to apachemq

Tags: activemq-classic, jmx, jconsole

activemq : apache-activemq-5.14.0

jconsole using jdk1.7

I have started the activemq which comes with the jetty server. Minor  change to make the jmx enable is  by making change in activemq.xml

managementContext createConnector="true" --- default is false

when i start  i am seeing the message 
JMX consoles can connect to service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi

So I start Jconsole  use remote process and use service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi

with no password : it says secure/insecure  connection failed: not sure where the problem is

Any help is really appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For jmx default credentials are admin:activemq https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/assembly/src/release/conf/jmx.password

Answer (score 0):

The default username/password are: admin/admin