# ActiveMQ and ActiveMQ Browser can't be connected

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I know the question has been asked many times here and I have followed many of the conversations but no luck for me. ActiveMQ Browser and ActiveMQ can't be connected.

So I'm asking here again with full information I have locally.

### Env information:

1. JDK 1.8
2. Windows 10
3. ActiveMQ 5.15.3
4. ActiveMQ Browser 2.5.2.8

### ActiveMQ Config

```
    <managementContext>
        <managementContext createConnector="false" />
    </managementContext>
```

ActiveMQ bat file
set ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1616 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=%ACTIVEMQ_CONF%/jmx.password -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=%ACTIVEMQ_CONF%/jmx.access

### ActiveMQ Browser Connection Config

service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://E105756:1616/jmxrmi
role: admin
password: activemq

### Exception

Could not start QBrowserV2
Failed to connect to ActiveMQ JMX Server.

Please make sure input value of JMX service URL and/or User, Password are correct.

Input JMX URL : service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://E105756:1616/jmxrmi

Notes:
I have tried with below options already
Option 1: Using createConnector = "true"
Option 2: Using rmi port 1098

I'm still getting exception when trying to connect from ActiveMQ Browser

Please help

Nghia

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093003/apache-activemq-browser-cant-connect-to-jmx-console

Comment: Yes, but no luck. I believe something I missing with my local setup but can't find out.

Comment: have you tried to connect to with VisualVM ?

Comment: No, could you tell me what it is

Comment: have a look at http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650653/jconsole-to-connect-to-apachemq

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132017/jmx-doesnt-seem-to-be-working-with-activemq/41151796#41151796

Comment: I'm enable to connect by using jConsole but ActiveMQBroswer is still throwing the same exception.

Comment: Thank you a lot @HassenBennour for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling around, finally ActiveMQ and ActiveMQ Browser are happy together.

Here is all my configurations

**1. activemq.xml**

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" useJmx="true">

<managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="true" rmiServerPort="1098"  connectorPort="1099"/>
        </managementContext>
```

**2. activemq.bat**

> set ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=%ACTIVEMQ_CONF%/jmx.password
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=%ACTIVEMQ_CONF%/jmx.access

**3. ActiveMQ 5.15.3 start log**

> C:\work\soft\apache-activemq-5.15.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.15.3\bin>activemq
>   start Java Runtime: Oracle Corporation 1.8.0_101 C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre   Heap sizes: current=1005056k 
>   free=994570k  max=1005056k
>       JVM args: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=C:\work\soft\apache-activemq-5.15.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.15.3\bin..\conf/jmx.password
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=C:\work\soft\apache-activemq-5.15.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.15.3\bin..\conf/jmx.access
>   -Xms1G -Xmx1G -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\work\soft\apache-activemq-5.15.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.15.3\bin..\conf\login.config
>   -Dactivemq.classpath=C:\work\soft\apache-activemq-5.15.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.15.3\bin..\conf;C:\work\soft\apache-activemq-5.15.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.15.3\bin../conf;C:\work\soft\apache-activemq-5.15.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.15.3\bin../conf;
>   -Dactivemq.home=C:\work\soft\apache-activemq-5.15.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.15.3\bin.. -Dactivemq.base=C:\work\soft\apache-activemq-5.15.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.15.3\bin.. -Dactivemq.conf=C:\work\soft\apache-activemq-5.15.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.15.3\bin..\conf
>   -Dactivemq.data=C:\work\soft\apache-activemq-5.15.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.15.3\bin..\data
>   -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\work\soft\apache-activemq-5.15.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.15.3\bin..\data\tmp
>   Extensions classpath:
>   [C:\work\soft\apache-activemq-5.15.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.15.3\bin..\lib,C:\work\soft\apache-activemq-5.15.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.15.3\bin..\lib\camel,C:\work\soft\apache-activemq-5.15.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.15.3\bin..\lib\optional,C:\work\soft\apache-activemq-5.15.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.15.3\bin..\lib\web,C:\work\soft\apache-activemq-5.15.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.15.3\bin..\lib\extra]
>   ACTIVEMQ_HOME:
>   C:\work\soft\apache-activemq-5.15.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.15.3\bin..
>   ACTIVEMQ_BASE:
>   C:\work\soft\apache-activemq-5.15.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.15.3\bin..
>   ACTIVEMQ_CONF:
>   C:\work\soft\apache-activemq-5.15.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.15.3\bin..\conf
>   ACTIVEMQ_DATA:
>   C:\work\soft\apache-activemq-5.15.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.15.3\bin..\data
>   Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml  INFO | Refreshing
>   org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@1554909b: startup date
>   [Fri Mar 02 11:03:24 CST 2018]; root of context hierarchy  INFO |
>   Using Persistence Adapter:
>   KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[C:\work\soft\apache-activemq-5.15.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.15.3\bin..\data\kahadb]
>   INFO | KahaDB is version 6  ***INFO | JMX consoles can connect to
>   service:jmx:rmi://localhost:1098/jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi*** 
>   INFO |
>   PListStore:[C:\work\soft\apache-activemq-5.15.3-bin\apache-activemq-5.15.3\bin..\data\localhost\tmp_storage]
>   started  INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.3 (localhost,
>   ID:E105756-56074-1520010210044-0:1) is starting  INFO | Listening for
>   connections at:
>   tcp://E105756:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
>   INFO | Connector openwire started  INFO | Listening for connections
>   at:
>   amqp://E105756:5672?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
>   INFO | Connector amqp started  INFO | Listening for connections at:
>   stomp://E105756:61613?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
>   INFO | Connector stomp started  INFO | Listening for connections at:
>   mqtt://E105756:1883?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
>   INFO | Connector mqtt started  WARN |
>   ServletContext@o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4241e0f4{/,null,STARTING}
>   has uncovered http methods for path: /  INFO | Listening for
>   connections at
>   ws://E105756:61614?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
>   INFO | Connector ws started  INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.3 (localhost,
>   ID:E105756-56074-1520010210044-0:1) started  INFO | For help or more
>   information please see: http://activemq.apache.org  INFO | No Spring
>   WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath  INFO | ActiveMQ
>   WebConsole available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/  INFO | ActiveMQ Jolokia
>   REST API available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/api/jolokia/  INFO |
>   Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'  INFO | No Spring
>   WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath  INFO |
>   jolokia-agent: Using policy access restrictor
>   classpath:/jolokia-access.xml

**4. ActiveMQ Broswer version 2.5.2.8**

**5. Download** https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-web/5.15.3 and copy to ActiveMQ Broswer installation folder.

**6. Download** http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/activemq/activemq-all/5.15.3/activemq-all-5.15.3.jar and copy to ActiveMQ Broswer installation folder.

**7. Change the run_activemq_browser.bat**

> start "ActiveMQBrowser" javaw -Xms128m -Xmx512m -splash:cube.png -cp
>   .\QBrowserV2_Neo.jar;.\activemq-web-5.15.3.jar;.\activemq-all-5.15.3.jar;.\jide-oss-2.6.2.jar;.\imq.jar;.\jms.jar;.\imqadmin_ja.jar;.\imqadmin.jar;.\imqutil_ja.jar;.\imqutil.jar;.\imqjmx.jar;.\imqjmx_ja.jar
>   com.qbrowser.ActiveMQBrowser

**8. See the connection configuration from ActiveMQ Browser**
JMX URL: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
JMX Role: admin
JMX Password: activemq